# Show text at bottom with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I searched in SO and Google but I can't find my answer. I want to do a simple thing, but I don't know how to do it. Let me explain:

I'm making a website in HTML and CSS using Bootstrap. In this website, I put some buttons as glyphicons as you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/Jp59ZO1.png (I can't post images yet).

Here is the code of the key button, rest of them is the same:

```
<a class="button" target="_blank" href="https://keybase.io/adolphenom">
    <i class="fa fa-key fa-lg"></i>
</a>
```

What I want to do is when I put the cursor on the button, it shows a text at bottom of the button (CSS of the text is a color and a font, it doesn't worry me so much right now).

I tried with two or three tutorials I found but It doesn't fit in my requirements.

Could you help me, please?

Thanks in advance!

---

Now I have another problem. I did what @monkeyinsight said to me (but not with a div but with a span, div breaks every other elemens in the html), and I have another problem:

When I put off the cursor of the icon, but I put on the text (because I go down and not up), this happens: http://i.imgur.com/Ld3AFMC.png Text doesn't disappear :(

Could you help me again, please? Thanks you!

Code of css':

```
span {
    position: relative;
}

a.button {
  color: #00628B;
  margin-left: 7.5px;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease-in, background 0.15s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: color 0.15s ease-in, background 0.15s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: color 0.15s ease-in, background 0.15s ease-in;
  -o-transition: color 0.15s ease-in, background 0.15s ease-in;
  transition: color 0.15s ease-in, background 0.15s ease-in;
}

a.button:hover, 
a.button:focus {
  color: #575757;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

.twitter:hover::after, 
.twitter:focus::after {
  font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  content: "Contact by email";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: -65px;
  color: #81A594;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Span's code:

```
<span class="twitter">
  <a class="button" target="_blank" href="mailto:adolphenom@gmail.com">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i>
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use CSS pseudo element `::after` and assign content i.e. `{content: 'twitter'}`

Comment: Could you post an example, please? :)

Comment: That's ok, it's just what I want, but there's a problem: when I put your CSS code and change background, font, etc., it's ok, but the possition of the text is not at bottom of the icon, see: http://i.imgur.com/JtnFlFi.png

Comment: you should set style of icon `{ position: relative }`

Comment: is there anyway that text doesn't be a link? I explain: button is in <a> tag, but I just what the text for explaining what is each button, but not a link.

Comment: @adolphenom you can place link in empty div and rewrite it so your ::after will be child of that element